# Identify chess piece from image in python

Tags: python, image-processing, image-recognition

I have images of the following type

[image]
[image]

etc..

What would be the easiest way of identifying what piece it is and if it is black or white? Do I need to use machine learning or is there an easier way?

Comment: Yep, machine learning is the way to go.

Comment: See the meta questions [Which Stack Exchange website for machine learning and computational algorithms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130524/303080) and also [Stack Exchange site to ask questions about computer vision?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2794/163067) for suggestions where you may find additional information.

Comment: If it's always an image from a fixed set of 12 images then you don't need any machine learning. If the images are all different colours, outlines, shapes from different journals, newspapers and websites then you maybe do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your inputs. If all of your data looks like this (nice and clean, with contours being identical, just background and color changes), you could probably use some kind of pixel + color matching and you could be good to go.

You definitely know that deep learning and machine learning only approximate function (functions of pixels in this case), if you can find it (the function) without using those methods (with sensible amount of work), you always should.

And no, machine learning is not a silver bullet, you get an image and you throw it into convolutional neural networks black-box magic and you get your results, that's not the point.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but deep learning might be just an overkill to recognize a known set  of images. Use template matching!
https://machinelearningmastery.com/using-opencv-python-and-template-matching-to-play-wheres-waldo/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using machine learning (plan or convolutional neural nets). This isn't that hard of a problem, but you have to do manual work of creating proper dataset with lots of pictures.

*For example:* For each piece you need to create picture with white/black field color. And you have to do different combinations, different chess piece sets vs. different table color schema. In order to make the system more robust to color schema you can try different color channels.

There are lots of questions, will the pictures you test always be in same resolution? If they aren't then you should also take that into consideration when creating dataset.